# React Native Navigation header hide

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I do not know how to set the header.

I want to set the back button to appear in the header.

When I enter Chatting in MainTab, I want to set back button in Chatting header.

However, both the header set in LoginScene and the header set in ChattingScene are displayed.

In chatting, using static navigationOptions to null the header does not create a back button.

I want to solve this problem.

**Navigator.js**

```
const ChattingScene = createStackNavigator({
 Chatting: {screen: Chatting}
 ...
},
{
 headerMode: 'float'
})

const MainScene = createStackNavigator({
 MainTab: {screen: MainTab},
 ChattingScene: {screen: ChattingScene}
},
{
 headerMode: 'none'
})

const SignUpScene = createStackNavigator({
 SignUp: {screen: SignUp},
 PWDSearch: {screen: PWDSearch},
},
{
 headerMode: 'none'
})

const LoginScene = createStackNavigator({
 LoginUI: {screen: LoginUI},
 SignUpScene: {screen: SignUpScene},
 MainScene: {screen: MainScene},
},
{
 initialRoutName: 'LoginUI',
 headerMode: 'float',
})

const HomeScene = createStackNavigator({
 LoginScene: {screen: LoginScene}
},
{
 headerMode: 'none'
})

export default class Navigator extends Component {
 render() {
  return(
   <HomeScene />
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react-navigation Component?

I don't know why you are stacking up bunch of stackNavigators, but I recommend not to do it. Because this makes it hard to control or aware of the navigators state. Which makes it harder to navigate through your application.

**Result:** You are already stuck on a problem!

I will help you out to clean you navigators if you're using react-navigation as your navigator.